# Positioning slide content to the right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a slider but I am really struggling to show content on the right hand side to support the image on the left hand side.

I have created a replica working model on jsfiddle here [Link to demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ssh2qjsu/1/)

As you can see below in my HTML I need content to the right inside of the `slide-1` and `slide-2`

```
<section class="new-angle-slider">
<div class="mask">
<ul class="images">
   <li class="slide-1 animated fadeInLeft">
      <img class="logo animated fadeInDown" src="http://mysite.co.uk/jbh-web/wp-content/themes/JBH/assets/img/slide-1.png" alt="Inside 8" title="Inside 8">
Content here to be on the right hand side.
```

```
<ul class="triggers">
   <li>0</li>
   <li>1</li>
</ul>
<span class="control prev">Prev</span>
<span class="control next">Next</span>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle :  https://jsfiddle.net/ssh2qjsu/7/

The code I updated is this:

Your HTML: just added a div with class overlay after ul in mask di

```
    <section class="new-angle-slider">
<div class="mask">
<ul class="images">
   <li class="slide-1 animated fadeInLeft">
      <img class="logo animated fadeInDown" src="http://jbhconcept.co.uk/jbh-web/wp-content/themes/JBH/assets/img/slide-1.png" alt="Inside 8" title="Inside 8">
      <div class="overlay">
This is where you can put your content for slide-1
</div>
   </li>
   <li class="slide-2 animated fadeInLeft">
      <img class="logo animated fadeInDown" src="http://jbhconcept.co.uk/jbh-web/wp-content/themes/JBH/assets/img/slide-2.png" alt="Inside 8" title="Inside 8">
   </li>
   <div class="overlay">
This is where you can put your content for slide 2
</div>
</ul>

</div>

<ul class="triggers">
   <li>0</li>
   <li>1</li>
</ul>
<span class="control prev">Prev</span>
<span class="control next">Next</span>
</section>
```

Here is you new CSS code for both of the div

```
.mask {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
 }
.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height:100%;
  width:40%;
  background-color:red;
}
```